# Washed out colors in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hdmi, nvidia-graphics-card, colors, dvi

The colors of my digital graphics outputs (DVI and HDMI) are washed out (desaturated) only on one of my displays, but using my analog (VGA) output always results in correct colors.

I've excluded these causes through experimentation:

- The display
- The cable
- The graphics card, or rather its DVI and HDMI outputs

It's therefore a software problem. How do I correct the colors?

- Windows 10
- Geforce GTX 550 Ti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant settings are in Nvidia Control Panel, unintuitively in the section **Change Resolution**:

1. Select *Use Nvidia color settings*
2. Change *Dynamic Range* from *Limited* to *Full*

Apply and the colors are back to normal.